# Does Quantum GIS recognize QDGC information?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

So a bit of background on what I am working on:
We are in the process of assisting a wildlife institution in South Africa with trying to take their information and surfacing it in a commercially available BI tool.

As part of their data they store Quarter Degree Grid Cell information about an extremely endangered mammal (Not Rhinos). They do not want to specify precisely where they spotted the animal due to the risk of poachers getting hold of the co-ordinates and poaching the animal.

The problem:
I have not come across a tool that naively recognizes QDGC information, and I don't want to start writing custom code for them as they don't have the skills to support the solution should something go wrong in future. This means that the solution that we will deliver will not be sustainable, which is definitely not ideal.

What I would like:
So my question is does Quantum GIS recognize QDGC information? If not, could the functionality be built in to the tool? If still not, could you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you give an example how this QDGC data is stored? A text-based file with a header line could be imported as delimited text.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to start off is downlaoding QDGC grid files from [here](http://www.mindland.com/wp/qdgc-global-national-level-coverage/), unzipping the shapefiles and adding one or several new columns as needed.

You can make the unneeded columns invisible in the layer properties to make data input easier.

If you have the data in delimited text form, you can add that too, and join the tables on common attribute in the QDGC field.